# Update list in for loop using list.append

Tags: python-3.x

The variable mult is not updated as the program runs. What is the issue with this code? The run results show me that the loop is actually working as I wanted but for the list update and final print

```
number = 18

for i in range(int(number/2)):
    i += 1
    mults = []
    if number % i == 0:
        mults = mults.append(i)
        print(i)
    elif number % i != 0:
        pass
    elif i == int(number/2):
        print(mults)
```

with this other code I get the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

```
number = 18
mults = []
for i in range(int(number/2)):
    i += 1
    if number % i == 0:
        mults = mults.append(i)
        print(i)
    elif number % i != 0:
        pass
print(mults)
```

Comment: you are resetting `mults` every time it loops, is that desirable ?

Comment: `mults = mults.append(int(i))`: that can't work either...

Comment: btw: `int(number/2)` => `number//2`. and don't tamper with `i` while in the loop..., print the result _after_ the for loop instead of checking the last index, which allows you to use `else` instead of `elsif`.

Comment: @MooingRawr No I actually want to end up with the expected values of i (according to my conditions) in the list mult. How can I do this?

Comment: With this other code:

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 18
mults = []
for i in range(int(number/2)):
    i += 1

    if number % i == 0:
        mults.append(i)
        print(i)
    elif number % i != 0:
        pass
print(mults)
```

Few notes, move `mults` outside of the for loop so you aren't over writing it every time the loop runs.

You don't need that last elif statement, just `print(mults)` when the for loop is done, is basically the last elif statement.

`mults.append(i)` is in line meaning it changes the list `mults` automatically and you don't need to reassign it.

Comment: Thanks, I saw my never to be repeated mistakes

Comment: Welp if it fixed your issue maybe consider accepting the answer, else maybe someone else would come along with a better answer you can accept

Comment: I can't yet, but soon as my reputation will permit me it will be done